# How do i randomly select more than one item from a list in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do i randomly select more than one item from a list in excel ?

For example:-

```
Column A    Column B
Itemcode    Quantity
COM#004     2
COM#005     3
COME001     10
COMT000     3
COMT001     3
COMH000     1
COMH000     1
COM#006     2
CT100H000   1
```

Inputs:-
the number of item to select

for example :- the number of item to select = 6

```
COME001
COMT000
COM#004
COM#006
COMT001
COMH000
```

after an set of items been selected, quantity has to be reduced. should be able to pick the same item in the next select till its quantity gets zero

Comment: You probably need helper columns for selection, and probably another range where you store previous selection. Other approach could be a macro. Describing a bit more your process would help finding a solution.

Comment: for example:- I have full list of items with available quantity. I need to generate random list [mutilple list] of more than one item picked from the given list. I need an option to select number of items per random list and till the quantity is greater than zero item has to be picked from the given list.

Answer (score 0):

Place the **number of desired samples** in *D1* and in *C1* enter:

```
=IF(ROWS($1:1)>$D$1,"",INDEX($A$2:$A$10,RANDBETWEEN(1,9)))
```

and copy down:

[image]